# How to update to phonegap 2.6.0 for a Blackberry project?

Tags: cordova, blackberry, phonegap-build

I am trying to update a Blackberry project to 2.6.0 on phonegap,  but there is no tutorial on how to do that.

The guides only goes up to 2.0.0

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/guide_upgrading_blackberry_index.md.html#Upgrading%20Cordova%20BlackBerry

Does anyone know what steps to follow?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to update my Blackberry projects as well and have also not been able to find any current updating info.

I've left a request on Phonegap's site, maybe someone will respond over there. Here's the link to my posting on [PhoneGap's blog](http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/04/30/pg-270-released/)

Rob